# Repository of LaTeX Feynman diagram templates with pictures

Tags: diagrams, examples, feynmf, repositories

I have over the last few years drawn a lot of Feynman diagrams in `LaTeX` with `Feynmf` and `mpost`. The results are nice, but time-consuming! For non-physicists, a Feynman diagram is an image made of lines which often need math labels, e.g. this Feynman diagram from wiki, which, although not made with `Feynmf`, gives you an idea...

[image]

I would like to start a repository of code for Fenyman diagrams for people to copy from, to save them time. Ideally, it could show `LaTeX` source and `pdf` or `png` output side-by-side, so that people could spot a diagram they wanted/wanted to modify, and copy and paste the `LaTeX`.

What is the best platform? `git-hub` etc? I guess this is a common request for `LaTeX` codes, to have code and output side-by-side?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe the guys over at [texample.net](http://texample.net) might be able to host this. The actual maintainer @StefanKottwitz is also active over here so maybe you may want to ask him.